# NodeJs App + AWS EC2 + Nginx + Websocket configuration

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, websocket, ffmpeg

im running a Nodejs app on a Ec2 instance. The app runs node-rtsp-stream that outputs a websocket witch then uses with jsmpeg to display on the web browser.

**NGINX config port 80 (this works fine)**

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

location / {

    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
```

**NGINX websocket config (this doesnt)**

```
http {
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream websocket {
    server ws://localhost:9999;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

**app.js**

```
Stream = require('node-rtsp-stream')

stream = new Stream({
  name: 'stream',
  streamUrl: 'rtsp://demo:demo@ipvmdemo.dyndns.org:554/onvif-media/media.amp',
  wsPort: 9999,
  ffmpegOptions: { // options ffmpeg flags
    '-stats': '', // an option with no neccessary value uses a blank string
    '-r': 30 // options with required values specify the value after the key
  }
})
```

**Script tag on HTML**

```
player = new JSMpeg.Player('ws://localhost:9999', {
      canvas: document.getElementById('canvas')
```

Should this be calling for **'ws://localhost:9999'** or something else?. On Browser says that can not find **'ws://localhost:9999'**

Each nginx config file is stored in sites-available

Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: wow nine hours ago i just searched this in google thats some great seo